# "Could not establish connection. Permission denied(public key) " error when connecting to AWS EC2 instance using VSCode

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2

These are the steps I took that are giving me an error message:

1. Logged into AWS, selected my AMI, and clicked on "Launch Instance from AMI"
2. Selected my instance type, my key pair name, and scrolled down and clicked launch
3. Using the Remote SSH extension on VS Code, I added a new SSH Host
4. It then required me to enter an SSH Connection Command, so I entered ec2-user@ my public IP address for my instance
5. Changed my HostName, User, and Host
   Then I received the error listed in the title
   [What I entered in VS Codebefore getting the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drdxt.png)

I was expecting it to connect to a set up the SSH host and connect me to the right terminal

Comment: What is the error, your image does not have error?

Comment: The error that appears after that is what is listed in the title of my question

Comment: The error message is saying that the private keypair provided does not match the public keypair stored on the instance. Try connecting manually using `ssh -vvv -i /home/user/Downloads/Nazia2.pem ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS`. The `-vvv` will turn on debugging and might help you diagnose the situation.

Comment: Go to your ec2, there you will see connect to instance, using ssh there will be steps follow that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Permission denied (public key)" error typically indicates that the SSH client was unable to authenticate with the server using the provided key. This can happen for a variety of reasons, but one common cause is that the SSH key specified in the SSH configuration file (often located at ~/.ssh/config) does not match the key associated with the EC2 instance.

To check if you are using the right key, you can do the following:

1. Check the key pair name you selected when launching the instance in the AWS Management Console. Make sure that this key pair is the same one that you are using to connect via SSH.
2. Verify that the private key file associated with the key pair is located on your local machine, and that the correct file path is specified in your SSH configuration file. The default location for SSH keys on macOS and Linux is `~/.ssh/`
3. Check the permissions on the private key file. SSH keys should have restrictive permissions to prevent unauthorized access. The file should be readable only by the user who owns it, and should not be accessible by anyone else. To set the correct permissions, run the following command in your terminal:
   `chmod 400 /path/to/private/key`

If none of the above steps resolve the issue, you may want to check the logs on the remote server for more information about the authentication failure. The log file is typically located at /var/log/auth.log on Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions.